# Xamarin Android Source - Build Error

Tags: android, xamarin, android-ndk, xamarin.android

Xamarin have finally [open sourced](http://open.xamarin.com) Android, iOS and Forms.

I have raised a [forum issue](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/65656/xamarin-android-source-build-error?new=1) regarding 2 Error(s) that I'm receiving when executing the `make` command after `make prepare` successfully installs all of the dependencies.

I'm aware that the Xamarin team is now using SO for support so I'm hoping that someone from the team can provide an answer to the errors I'm receiving.

Specifically the fact that one of the errors relate to a missing header file as part of mono:

> /../../../external/mono/eglib/src/glib.h:22:26: fatal error: eglib-config.h: No such file or directory
>    #include 
>                             ^
>   compilation terminated.
>   make: *** [obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/monodroid/**/**/__/external/mono/support/nl.o] Error 1
>   macuser@macusers-MacBook-Pro:~/Documents/TFS/xamarin-android/src/monodroid$

**EDIT:** I noticed that the `xamarin-macios` source mentioned using `--recursive` when cloning the repository. So I tried that with the `xamarin-android` repository and was able to get further than before, although I still receive the following error:

> : error : Error initializing task XmlPeek: Not registered task XmlPeek.
>                   Build FAILED.
>                   Warnings:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> : error : Error initializing task XmlPeek: Not registered task XmlPeek. Build FAILED. Warnings:

You will need a mono >= 4.4.0 . We added a working implementation of XmlPeek to mono in 4.4.0 .

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll give it a shot and report back.

Comment: Beta 4.4 download link for anyone who's after it: http://www.mono-project.com/download/beta/

Comment: After installing 4.4.0 it compiles successfully. Thanks for your help!